# How to get key pressed as char in DrawingPanel

Tags: java, bluej

I'm putting together a simple game as part of a project in Java. I'm using a DrawingPanel window, and need to be able to get the current keyboard key pressed as a char. Specifically, I have the DrawingPanel class and a class for the game, and need to get the char variable from within the public static void main of the game class.

I noticed that DrawingPanel contains KeyListener methods, specifically onKeyDown, but I have no idea how to use this. It is a void method, so I don't know how I would get the key pressed as an output, nor do I know what the DPKeyEventHandler input is for.

Answer (score 0):

I think with some reading about KeyListeners in java, you will be able to do what you want.

To give you something to start, look at this code, and how it behaves:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class KeyEventClass extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

public KeyEventClass(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.addKeyListener(this);
    this.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("KeyTyped: ");
    if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED){
        System.out.println("No Unicode-Character typed!");
    }else{
        System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " typed!");
    }
    System.out.println("---");
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKeyChar() + ", Code: " + e.getKeyCode());
    System.out.println("Key-Location: " + e.getKeyLocation());
    System.out.println("---");
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("KeyReleased: ");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        System.out.println("ABORT!");
        System.exit(0);
    }    
    System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKeyChar() + ", Code: " + e.getKeyCode());
    System.out.println("---");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new KeyEventClass();
}
}
```

Some more information about it:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/a-complete-keylistener-example/